# Удаление через контекстное меню в ListView

Tags: база-данных, sqlite, listview

Есть таблица SQLite с колонками ID (autoincrement) и `NAME`

1. Получаю курсор(cursor) со значениями "NAME".
2. Передаю этот курсор в ArrayList list.
3. list  передаю в ListView.

Не работает удаление пункта меню через контекстное меню. Напишите, пожалуйста, недостающий кусок кода:

```
@Override 
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) { 
    AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo(); 
    switch (item.getItemId()) { 
        case ADD: 
            ... \\ добавление работает отлично!
            return true; 
        case DELETE: 
            \\НЕОБХОДИМЫЙ КОД
            return true; 
        default: 
            return super.onContextItemSelected(item); 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

1.Нужно получить объект `DBHelper`.

2.Выполнить открытие БД для записи - `getWritableDatabase()`.

3.Удалить запись с БД методом `delete(String table, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)`. Где `whereClause` это Ваш `ID` нажатого элемента `ListView`.

4.Закрыть БД.

5.Сообщить адаптеру что данные в БД были изменены для перерисовки `ListView`.